# Does Selenium WebDriver support robot framework?

Tags: java, facebook, frameworks, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Does Selenium WebDriver support Robot framework?
I have a script to log in facebook using java and Webdriver. Now I want to execute this using any framewrok. Is it possible to execute the tests using robot framework  written in java using Webdriver?

Thanks & Regards,
Shiva Oleti

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, Robot Framework has a library for [Selenium 1](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/) and [Selenium 2 / Webdriver](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library)

Comment: Yes, absolutely it does.  Robot Framework generally supports Java which implies usage of Selenium 2 API.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought there would be much issues. There is a dedicated library to help:

http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/

Comment: Does any one have sample program with java and robot framework using webdriver?

Comment: I think Robot Framework comes with some Java examples.  If not, here is one link: http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/robot-framework-tutorial-writing-keyword-libraries-in-java/